# Как зашифровать передаваемые данные в локальной сети?

Tags: json, http, api, сеть, криптография

Есть несколько устройств в локальной сети, у которых может быть непредсказуемый(динамический или могут поменять в настройках) ip адрес. Весь механизм управления этим устройством идет через http используя json. Для авторизации на устройстве планирую использовать логин и пароль.
Суть проблемы в том что в этой локальной сети не всегда может быть доступ в интернет, и то что в этой локальной сети могут быть "посторонние" лица.

Ищу адекватный способ защитить данные передаваемые между браузером(или другой программой) и этим устройством.

Предложите что-то вменяемое, пожалуйста, какой день голову ломаю!

Comment: интересно... почему слово посторонние в кавычках. инопланетяне чтоли )))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам нужно передавать сообщения из приложения в приложение, то используйте JWT, если вы хотите зашифровать весь трафик между машинами, и гарантировать, целостность и подлинность данных , то используйте систему систему шифрования с открытым и закрытым ключом.

Предлагаю использовать [JWT](https://jwt.io/)

Json Web Token. Это открытый стандарт RFC 7519 для представления заявок (claims) между двумя участниками.

Он представляет из себя структуру вида: 
Header.Payload.Signature, где заголовок и payload это запакованые в base64 json хэши. Здесь стоит обратить внимание на payload. Он может содержать в себе все что угодно, в принципе это может быть и просто client_id и какая-то другая информация о пользователе, но это не очень хорошая идея, лучше передавать там только ключ идентификатор, а сами данные хранить где-то в другом месте.

Вот несколько заметок, которые помогут улучшить секьюрность при использовании JWT:

1. При создании токена, в его тело необходимо внести IP адрес пользователя. Затем при каждом запросе сверять это поле с тем адресом откуда поступил запрос. Таким образом, даже имея токен, злоумышленник не сможет воспользоваться им. Этот способ накладывает некоторые дополнительные неудобства для пользователя, например придётся авторизовываться заново каждый раз когда меняется его IP. Однако, в большинстве случаев это происходит не очень часто и не должно вызывать особого дискомфорта.
2. Можно, конечно, при каждом запросе дёргать вашу БД и сверять данные из токена с данными в записи пользователя. Иными словами, при каждом запросе обращаться к БД, доставать юзера и убеждаться в том, что данный запрос может быть выполнен, при этом что и как сверять зависит только от вашей задумки. Можно проверять, не заблокирован ли пользователь, не менял ли он пароль с момента выдачи токена, подходящая ли у него роль и т.д. Этот способ довольно грубый, но максимально эффективный. Тем не менее, есть более практичный и интересный способ проверки, не насилующий вашу основную БД — смотрите пункт 3.
3. Хранение списка актуальных токенов (т.н. «белый список») в отдельной высокопроизводительной БД, например Redis или Memcahed. При каждом запросе, после обычной проверки токена на валидность, мы также проверяем его наличие в этой БД. Если по какой-то причине его там не оказалось — значит запрос не может быть выполнен и нужно получить новый токен. Таким образом, после каких-то критических действий с аккаунтом (смена пароля, смена роли, бан и т.д.) мы просто удаляем из белого списка все токены, относящиеся к этому аккаунту.

Answer (score 1):

Используй https с самоподписанными сертификатами.  Прочитайте например https://habrahabr.ru/post/192446/

Comment: Не совсем подходит, так как ip адрес может поменяться по желанию пользователя или dhcp. Конечно как вариант можно создать скрипт автоматической перегенерации ключа при смене IP адреса, но тогда их нужно заново закидывать в клиенты и т.д.

Comment: не важно какой ip. Сделай сертификат на домен. А как повесить домен к динамическому ip -  решений десятки

Comment: более того фиксированный ip в dhcp вообще не проблема. Да же блондинко по картинкам сможет сделать на своем роутере

Comment: около сотни устройств, устройства не имеют выхода в интернет, нет контролирующего единого сервера для них. IP может поменяться при различных обстоятельствах уже на объекте.
Устройство не сможет обновить свой домен, и блондинку не попросить перезалиписать все домены для всех устройств

Comment: Ну значит у вас не техническая проблема, а организационная. Нет ни одной малейшей технической причины, что бы не сделать фиксированный ip внутри локальной сети для определенного устройства.

Comment: Можно еще закрытый и открытый ключ http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/руководство_по_ubuntu_server/безопасность/certificates